# MKMap zoom to include annotations and region

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to set the zoom level of the map to include just the annotations, but also don't zoom below say a 3 mile radius, but I also don't the annotations touching the side of the screens. Further, I would also like the annotations once zoomed to be within the bottom half self.view (my map takes up the entire screen).

I tried the following two ways and neither works.

// #1 /////  Always zooms to show my annotation in Texas, zoomed out to far I can't even see US states

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)aMapView {

if([aMapView.annotations count] == 0) {
    return;
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
topLeftCoord.longitude = -180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations){
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
//Add a little space on both sides
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;
//Add a little extra space on bith sides
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

region = [aMapView regionThatFits:region];
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

// #2 ///// This works best, but it zooms in to much; right on top of a house, if there is only one annotation, but I want to see the one annotation and a 4 mile radius. So I never want to zoom less than having 4 square miles shown, UNLESS the user manually zooms it.

```
MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
{

    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
}
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(300, 300, 100, 300) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;

    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        }else{
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
    }
    if (zoomRect.size.width == 0.10) /* for single annotation available in map */
    {
        zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(zoomRect.origin.x, zoomRect.origin.y, 100000, 100000);
    }

    [[self mapView] setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50) animated:YES];
```

Comment: When you say homeAnnotation do you mean the "user annotation" or are you trying to say "annotation"?

Comment: So I need all this zooming to happen as you have coded it, but I need it to zoom the center of the map always in the center. With this code the center of my map might be a building in SF. When this above code executes and their are no annotations it puts the center of the map over the ocean near SF Bay? Instead it should just zoom out without panning?